# Duvida depurando um programa

Tags: c

Estava depurando um programa e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida, 
tinha arquitetura é 32 Bits Intel e tinha a seguinte instrução MOV EAX, DWORD PTR SS[0X401049], e abaixo dessa instrução tinha o seguinte comando MOV EDX, DWORD PTR SS[0X40104A]. Minha dúvida e que na primeira instrução o registro EAX recebeu 4 byte de dados , e na segunda apenas um byte de dados.

O por que disto sendo que cada endereço de memória em uma arquitetura de 32 bits tem 32 bits.

Não teria que transferir 4 bytes também à segunda instrução?

Comment: Duas coisas. Coloque títulos mais descritivos do seu real problema. Nem comece com dúvida, porque todo mundo que posta um pergunta aqui está com dúvida. É redundante e não descreve o problema. Coloque *tags* que tem a ver com o problema. Não use"C" em todas suas perguntas. Só use esta *tag* quando ela é sobre C. E sempre dê o máximo de detalhes possível. Mostre como você chegou à conclusão postada na pergunta, quem sabe sua afirmação é que está errada.

Comment: Do que consigo ver moveu 2x 4 bytes. DWORD é 4 bytes não consigo ver o problema.

Comment: Falta-te um `;` na linha 42 ... ou porquê C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não necessáriamente precisam ser 4 bytes. Por exemplo, quando estamos trabalhando com diversos tamanhos de tipos podemos usar tanto 4 bytes como 8 bytes como 2 bytes. Não importa qual o tamanho pois a arquitetura do computador corrige essa falha pulando para o próximo valor depois da palavra.

Por exemplo, se você usa um char, ele estará ocupando apenas 256 bits da palavra, o que é referente à 2^8. Nós sabemos que se a arquitetura de um computador é 32bits então cada palavra possuirá 2^32, porém não é um fator determinante. Cada tipo possui um certo tamanho na arquitetura, independente dela.

Dê uma olhada em [climits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) e veja do que estou falando, lá você encontra todas os limites em bits dos tipos em C. Ficará evidente que não é necessário sempre ocupar os 4 bytes de uma palavra!